# "Mi Kel Komocha" corresponding to 13 Attributes of Mercy

Tags: thirteen-attributes, micah

> מִי אֵל כָּמוֹךָ נוֹשא עָוֹן וְעוֹבֵר עַל פֶּשַׁע לִשְׁאֵרִית
>   נַחֲלָתוֹ לֹא הֶחֱזִיק לָעַד אַפּוֹ כִּי חָפֵץ חֶסֶד הוּא

The words of 'Mi Kel Komocha' supposedly correspond to the 13 Attributes of Mercy (ה' ה' אל רחום וחנוך וכו). In many Siddurim, the 13 Attributes are superimposed over the phrases of Mi Kel Komocha.

In what way are they connected?

Answer (score 2):

The Zohar says, that the thirteen middos of micha are upper level middos, and the 13 from Moshe are the lower of those middos.  The Gr"a explains, that the upper middos are the "inner" ones, and the lower ones are the "outer" middos.

I have seen this explained - in the footnote of the attached sefer - as follows:
If you go to a country and see the people interacting with each other [kind or mean], you will assume that the leader of the country acts that way. When people act with mercy, you can tell the ruler acts with mercy, and so on. The upper level middos, are the ones that Hashem himself uses "inside", while people emulating Hashem use the lower level of those same middos "outside".

The way Hashem uses those middos - the upper middos, and how we are to use them - the lower middos, are described in detail in the first perek of the sefer Tomer Devorah.

[image: Sefer Tomer Devorah with a pirush]

Answer (score 1):

Mi Keil Kamocha are the 13 Atributes of Mercy given to Michah. From here: https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/3609722/jewish/What-Are-the-13-Attributes-of-Mercy.htm#footnoteRef10a3609722

> Kabbalists explain that besides the 13 attributes which G‑d said to
>   Moses, there is another set which was later said to the prophet
>   Micah:
>
> מִי אֵ-ל כָּמוֹךָ / mee E-l kamocha — Who is a G‑d like you (in
>   compassion);
>   נֹשֵׂא עָו‍ֹן / noseh avon — who bears iniquity;
>   וְעֹבֵר
>   עַל פֶּשַׁע / ve’over al pesha — and overlooks sin;
>   לִשְׁאֵרִית
>   נַחֲלָתוֹ / lishi’eirit nachalato — For the remnant of his heritage;
>
> לֹא הֶחֱזִיק לָעַד אַפּוֹ / lo hechzik le’ad apoh — He does not retain
>   his anger forever;
>   כִּי חָפֵץ חֶסֶד הוּא/ ki chafetz chesed hu — for
>   He desires kindness;
>   יָשׁוּב יְרַחֲמֵנוּ/ yashuv yerachamanu — He
>   shall again have mercy on us;
>   יִכְבֹּשׁ עֲו‍ֹנֹתֵינוּ / yichbosh
>   avonoteinu — and suppresses our iniquities;
>   וְתַשְׁלִיךְ בִּמְצֻלוֹת
>   יָם כָּל חַטֹּאתָם / vetashlich bimtzolet yam kol chatotam — casts our
>   sins into the depths of the sea;
>   תִּתֵּן אֱמֶת לְיַעֲקֹב / titein emet
>   le’Yaakov — You grant truth to Jacob;
>   חֶסֶד לְאַבְרָהָם / chesed
>   le’Avraham — kindness to Abraham;
>   אֲשֶׁר נִשְׁבַּעְתָּ לַאֲבֹתֵינוּ /
>   asher nishba’ata le’avotaynu — which You previously swore to our
>   forefathers;
>   מִימֵי קֶדֶם / mimei kedem — from the earliest days.

Comment: The question was to explain the connection between the two sets of Attributes, and explain how each of the 13 correspond.